# private sql connection database

Tags: magento2.3, database

I'm using magento 2, I want to use a private  sql connection with port
when I try to add this code to my env.php, it does not work

```
'db' => [
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => [
        'default' => [
            'host' => '',
            'port' => '',
            'dbname' => '',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'active' => '1'
        ]
    ]
],
```

help please

Comment: Go through this link - https://marcelhauri.ch/blog/magento2-custom-database-connection

Comment: I have the same issue!did you found the solution pls?